# How to extend the canvas to the size of the parent div with P5JS?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to add my canvas inside a specific div and I want it to be as big as the canvas size.

For example on this code I would like the canvas to be inside the div "p5-div" and to be as big as it is. Having in consideration that the size of the div is unpredictable because is set by css and this can change.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      #p5-div {
        width: 50%;
        height: 300px
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Sketch</h1>
    <div id="p5-div">
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js" integrity="sha512-NxocnqsXP3zm0Xb42zqVMvjQIktKEpTIbCXXyhBPxqGZHqhcOXHs4pXI/GoZ8lE+2NJONRifuBpi9DxC58L0Lw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script>
      function setup() {
        createCanvas(100, 100); // this has to be adapted in load time to the side of the div
      }

      function draw(){
        background(33);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To allocate your canvas inside an specific div you have to use this code in your `setup()`:

```
function setup() {
  const myCanvas = createCanvas(divWidth, divHeight);
  myCanvas.parent("div-id");
}
```

Now, in order to know the size of the canvas it gets a bit more complicated, this is my solution:

```
class Utils {
  // Calculate the Width in pixels of a Dom element
  static elementWidth(element) {
    return (
      element.clientWidth -
      parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("padding-left")) -
      parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("padding-right"))
    )
  }

  // Calculate the Height in pixels of a Dom element
  static elementHeight(element) {
    return (
      element.clientHeight -
      parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("padding-top")) -
      parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("padding-bottom"))
    )
  }
}
```

Then we can do:

```
function setup() {
  p5Div = document.getElementById("div-id");
  const p5Canvas = createCanvas(Utils.elementWidth(p5Div), Utils.elementHeight(p5Div));
  p5Canvas.parent(p5Div);
}
```